# Docker error on Mac: Get "https://192.168.64.2:2376/v1.24/containers/json": dial tcp 192.168.64.2:2376: i/o timeout

Tags: docker, macos

Installed Docker first time on Mac and got the below error.

```
User ~ % docker ps                        
Get "https://192.168.64.2:2376/v1.24/containers/json": dial tcp 192.168.64.2:2376: i/o timeout
```

Tried restarting Docker, uninstall and reinstall Docker and restarting Mac, nothing worked.
Tried from both home and office networks, same issue. Reset networking settings on Mac as well.

Comment: I suggest you look into this: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/792. Most likely you have an issue with network interfaces, if you have some virtualization tools installed there might be a conflict